# CodeBlocks Debugger shows the Breakpoint, but cant go further than that. Cannot find bounds of current function

Tags: c

I have a big problem with CodeBlocks right now.

If I make somewhere a breakpoint, and start the debugger, it will show the code until the breakpoint.

The problem starts here:

If I want to go to the next line for example, it won't work. In the Info Box/Console messages, there is a message called:

```
"In ?? () () "
"Cannot find bounds of current function"
```

What could it be?

Furthurmore, I noticed one thing when I compare CodeBlocks on my desktop PC with that on my Virtual Machine (on a Notebook). Is that on the Desktop he goes by a path that includes Python 2.7, while on my Notebook this path is nowhere visible.

I hope somebody can help me out! Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It is not the first time that I have encountered this problem, mainly your debugger must be hosted in a folder that contains incompatible characters, at least that is the reason I gave it, download MINGW or some debugger of the same style, what I did was create a path without special characters or spaces.

This is how I fixed it, I hope it work for you too.